# Windows 10 Wifi disabled at startup, unable to open network settings

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Recently, I've been getting this strange wifi issue where the wifi would be disabled when I boot into Windows 10.  I see the globe icon (instead of the wifi fan icon) in the system tray.  If I click on the globe and select Network & Internet Settings, the window will pop up for a split second and then auto disappears.  The only way for me to resolve this issue is to restart the PC and then everything will work fine.

My specs:

- Gigabyte B550I Aorus Pro AX
- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X
- RAM   32.0 GB
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 FE
- Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (driver is up-to-date)
- SATA 6 Samsung SSD 860 EVO 500GB (Ubuntu)
- NVMe Samsung SSD 980 Pro 500GB (Windows 10)

(I'm dual booting)

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Following a Windows update, a few months ago, I encountered a similar problem, where after hibernation or restart, the network became unavailable. Restarting the WLAN Service made the internet available again. Rather than having to open the Services CPL each time, the following script can be saved as a batch file and run as Administrator to stop and restart that service

```
  net stop wlansvc
  net start wlansvc
```

Subsequent Windows updates seemed to have fixed that issue, though.